# How to send data using internet on C language windows

Tags: c, windows, sockets, networking, communication

I am pretty new to socket programming and the C language. I want to teleoperate a robot over the internet for that I have to send some values to a robot computer. Here is my code...

```
            x = state.position_val[0];
            y = state.position_val[1];
            z = state.position_val[2];
            Rx = state.gimbal_joints[0]*1000;
            Ry= state.gimbal_joints[1]*1000;
            Rz = state.gimbal_joints[2]*1000;
            double arr[7] = { x, y, z, Rx, Ry, Rz, btonn };
            SAFEARRAY* psa = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_R8, 0, 7);
            void* data;
            SafeArrayAccessData(psa, &data);
            CopyMemory(data, arr, sizeof(arr));
            SafeArrayUnaccessData(psa);
            return psa;
```

These are the code snippets under the while loop at each loop this code gets the state value of the robot and creates an array that is further used for teleoperation. I need to send this array over the internet to another computer.
Please help me how to do this?

Comment: Sorry its tele robotics.

Comment: @sulemanAlikazmi don't say "sorry" but [edit] your question and remove irrelevant tags.

Comment: Since you have tagged the question with "windows", I am assuming that you are using the [Windows Sockets 2 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-start-page-2). Have you considered using the function [`send`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-send)?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I am very new to sockets. Please suggest me online resources. As when I searched mostly resources using linux. And I have tested the socket sample on same computer its works fine but when I start run client on one computer and client on other computer then program didn't work.

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/getting-started-with-winsock) is the official tutorial for Windows Sockets 2 API (Winsock).

Comment: "And I have tested the socket sample on same computer its works fine but when I start run client on one computer and client on other computer then program didn't work." -- If possible, please provide a [mre] of this problem. Also, "it didn't work" is not a useful error description. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this on Windows machine

1. Go to https://ngrok.com create an account
2. your robot should run ngrok client use following commands

```
ngrok authtoken xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ngrok tcp 80
```

3. **Forwarding tcp://3.tcp.ngrok.io:15842 -> localhost:80**
   Here ngrok will assign a local PORT to 80 and random port to outside network ie Interner exposed port. You have to add 80 and that port to your firewall rules of robot network device).
4. Goto https://whatismyipaddress.com/hostname-ip here put **3.tcp.ngrok.io** Look IP address box from ngrok console out. You will get your robot's global IP. that you can connect to your robot from anywhere in the world.
5. Following are the Client and Server examples that you can compile and run.

```
gcc .\Client.c -o Client
gcc .\Server.c -o Server
```

Client.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<unistd.h>
//Create a Socket for server communication
short SocketCreate(void)
{
    short hSocket;
    printf("Create the socket\n");
    hSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    return hSocket;
}
//try to connect with server
int SocketConnect(int hSocket)
{
    int iRetval=-1;
    int ServerPort = 15842;  // ngroks external tcp port
    struct sockaddr_in remote= {0};
    remote.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("3.134.xxx.xxx"); //Robot IP
    remote.sin_family = AF_INET;
    remote.sin_port = htons(ServerPort);
    iRetval = connect(hSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&remote,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    return iRetval;
}
// Send the data to the server and set the timeout of 20 seconds
int SocketSend(int hSocket,char* Rqst,short lenRqst)
{
    int shortRetval = -1;
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 20;  /* 20 Secs Timeout */
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    if(setsockopt(hSocket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_SNDTIMEO,(char *)&tv,sizeof(tv)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Time Out\n");
        return -1;
    }
    shortRetval = send(hSocket, Rqst, lenRqst, 0);
    return shortRetval;
}
//receive the data from the server
int SocketReceive(int hSocket,char* Rsp,short RvcSize)
{
    int shortRetval = -1;
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 20;  /* 20 Secs Timeout */
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    if(setsockopt(hSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO,(char *)&tv,sizeof(tv)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Time Out\n");
        return -1;
    }
    shortRetval = recv(hSocket, Rsp, RvcSize, 0);
    printf("Response %s\n",Rsp);
    return shortRetval;
}
//main driver program
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int hSocket, read_size;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char SendToServer[100] = {0};
    char server_reply[200] = {0};
    //Create socket
    hSocket = SocketCreate();
    if(hSocket == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Socket is created\n");
    //Connect to remote server
    if (SocketConnect(hSocket) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Sucessfully conected with server\n");
    printf("Enter the Message: ");
    gets(SendToServer);
    //Send data to the server
    SocketSend(hSocket, SendToServer, strlen(SendToServer));
    //Received the data from the server
    read_size = SocketReceive(hSocket, server_reply, 200);
    printf("Server Response : %s\n\n",server_reply);
    close(hSocket);
    shutdown(hSocket,0);
    shutdown(hSocket,1);
    shutdown(hSocket,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Server.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<unistd.h>
short SocketCreate(void)
{
    short hSocket;
    printf("Create the socket\n");
    hSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    return hSocket;
}
int BindCreatedSocket(int hSocket)
{
    int iRetval=-1;
    int ClientPort = 80; //Robot local port
    struct sockaddr_in  remote= {0};
    /* Internet address family */
    remote.sin_family = AF_INET;
    /* Any incoming interface */
    remote.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    remote.sin_port = htons(ClientPort); /* Local port */
    iRetval = bind(hSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&remote,sizeof(remote));
    return iRetval;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc, sock, clientLen, read_size;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    char client_message[200]= {0};
    char message[100] = {0};
    const char *pMessage = "hello aticleworld.com";
    //Create socket
    socket_desc = SocketCreate();
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Socket created\n");
    //Bind
    if( BindCreatedSocket(socket_desc) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed.");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("bind done\n");
    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc, 3);
    //Accept and incoming connection
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Waiting for incoming connections...\n");
        clientLen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        //accept connection from an incoming client
        sock = accept(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&client,(socklen_t*)&clientLen);
        if (sock < 0)
        {
            perror("accept failed");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Connection accepted\n");
        memset(client_message, '\0', sizeof client_message);
        memset(message, '\0', sizeof message);
        //Receive a reply from the client
        if( recv(sock, client_message, 200, 0) < 0)
        {
            printf("recv failed");
            break;
        }
        printf("Client reply : %s\n",client_message);
        if(strcmp(pMessage,client_message)==0)
        {
            strcpy(message,"Hi there !");
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(message,"Invalid Message !");
        }
        // Send some data
        if( send(sock, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0)
        {
            printf("Send failed");
            return 1;
        }
        close(sock);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can now send receive data between robot and your computer

Comment: But dear I am using Windows

Comment: That's what answer start with. Please read carefully.

Comment: `#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<unistd.h>`
These are the linux header file I guess. How can I replace these?

Comment: install msys64 https://www.msys2.org/. you will get your header files at location ```C:\msys64\usr\include\sys\socket.h and C:\msys64\usr\include\arpa\inet.h```. another option is Cygwin. If you want to go with the Windows POSIX compatibility then look into the Winsock library client-server.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. I tried, my program is running using ngrok established connection. But it works on LAN i.e connection established and sending and receiving data. But when I switched to WAN. The connection is still established but data couldn't transfer with the error "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine". But same configuration working on LAN i.e same wifi with internet but on wan it is not working.

Comment: I am also getting the error when I run ngrok https 80 this error pops up when I start browsing the https link provided by ngrok. The connection to https://1f29-119-160-2-26.ngrok.io was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client, but the client failed to establish a connection to the local address localhost:80.

Make sure that a web service is running on localhost:80 and that it is a valid address.

The error encountered was: dial tcp [::1]:80: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: There are some possibilities of this problem. 1) Windows Firewall blocking the incoming port. Add rules for TCP/UDP for the port range or Disable firewall 2) Check the same with your router build-in firewall. 3) Add Client-Server applications to the Network user group. 4) After start ngrok try to send data from Telenet to verify raw packets are sent from end to end.